# What is wrong with this http request? ENOTFOUND

Tags: javascript, gulp

This http request is in a gulpfile. I get the error message:

```
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://service.javascriptobfuscator.com/HttpApi.ashx https://service.javascriptobfuscator.com/HttpApi.ashx:80
```

Request

```
gulp.task("obfuscate", "Obfuscate this", function() {
    console.log("obfuscate this!");

    var proj = {
        "APIKey": "hidden",
        "APIPwd": "hidden",
        "Name": "Sample1",
        "ReplaceNames": true,
        "MoveStrings": true,
        "EncodeStrings": true,
        "items": [
            {
                "FileName": "test0.js",
                "FileCode": "function hello(x,y){var z=11;return x+y+z;}"
            },
            {
                "FileName": "test1.js",
                "FileCode": "var strs=['aaaa','bbbb','cccc','dddd','eeee','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789']"
            }
        ]
    };

    var options = {
        hostname: 'https://service.javascriptobfuscator.com/HttpApi.ashx',
        path: '',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/json'
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);
        //console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (body) {
            //console.log('Body: ' + body);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    //console.log(JSON.stringify(proj));

    // write data to request body
    req.write(JSON.stringify(proj));
    req.end();
});
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`hostname`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) is supposed to hold literally just the name of the host, you've put a full URL there.

Split that value into `protocol`, `hostname` and `path`. I.e.:

```
var options = {
    protocol: 'https:'
    hostname: 'service.javascriptobfuscator.com',
    path: '/HttpApi.ashx',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/json'
    }
};
```

The secret to interpreting the errormessage is to realize that "getaddrinfo" is a method that's used to do DNS lookups (i.e. it turns a host name into an IP address). If that method complains about "https://service.javascriptobfuscator.com/HttpApi.ashx", then something must have passed in the wrong value, as that's far more than just a host name.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I removed `https://` as part of the hostname.

The following edit fixed the problem:

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'service.javascriptobfuscator.com',
    path: '/HttpApi.ashx',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/json'
    }
};
```

Comment: You're missing the protocol, which means it'll default to HTTP, which is probably NOT what you want.